# Merge records in data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have the following example data set:

```
data.frame(SEX=c("M","F","M","F"),COMPLAINT=c("headache","headache", "dizziness", "dizziness"),
           reports=c(5,4,9,12), users = c(1250,3460,2500,1850))

  SEX COMPLAINT reports users
1   M  headache       5  1250
2   F  headache       4  3460
3   M dizziness       9  2500
4   F dizziness      12  1850
```

My question is how to merge rows 1 and 2 , and 3 and 4 so that my data frame is as follows:

```
 COMPLAINT reports_male reports_female users_male users_female
1  headache            5              4       1250         3460
2 dizziness            9             12       2500         1850
```

Anyone got a quick solution that I can use for a (much) larger dataset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use the `dcast` from `data.table` which can take multiple `value.var` columns and is quite efficient on big datasets

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df1), COMPLAINT ~ SEX, value.var = c("reports", "users"))
#    COMPLAINT reports_F reports_M users_F users_M
#1: dizziness        12         9    1850    2500
#2:  headache         4         5    3460    1250
```

Answer (score 2):

As seen in [How to reshape data from long to wide format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890584/how-to-reshape-data-from-long-to-wide-format), we can use `library(reshape2)` and then

`reshape(df, idvar = "COMPLAINT", timevar = "SEX", direction = "wide")`.

```
  COMPLAINT reports.M users.M reports.F users.F
1  headache         5    1250         4    3460
3 dizziness         9    2500        12    1850
```